# Add attributes/ parameters to existing method in a class

Tags: php, class, methods, parameters

I have a class admin user which has some rights to modify user data. I want to add two or more attributes to this method to complete the required functionality.

```
function update_user_by_admin($new_level, $user_id, $def_pass, $new_email, $active, $confirmation = "no", $staff_salary, $set_duty_timings) {
    $this->user_found = true;
    $this->user_access_level = $new_level;
    $this->set_staff_salary=$staff_salary;
    if ($def_pass != "" && strlen($def_pass) < 4) {
        $this->the_msg = "Password is too short use the min. of 4 chars.";
    } else {
        if ($this->check_email($new_email)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE %s SET access_level = %d, email = '%s', active = '%s', salary='salary'";
            $sql .= ($def_pass != "") ? sprintf(", pw = '%s'", md5($def_pass)) : "";
            $sql .= " WHERE id = %d";
            $sql_compl = sprintf($sql, $this->table_name, $new_level, $new_email, $active, $user_id);
            if (mysql_query($sql_compl)) {
                $this->the_msg = "Data is modified for user with id#<b>".$user_id."</b>";
                if ($confirmation == "yes") {
                    if ($this->send_confirmation($user_id)) {
                        $this->the_msg .= "<br>...a confirmation mail has been sent to the user.";
                    } else {
                        $this->the_msg .= "<br>...ERROR no confirmation mail is sent to the user.";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->the_msg = "Database error, please try again!";
            }
        } else {
            $this->the_msg = "The e-mail address is invalid!";
        }
    }
}
```

how do I add new parameter code here?

Comment: Your code looks incomplete as it doesn't include a class definition. Just add another function into your class for a new method.

Comment: I just want to add two more attributes to this method no inheritance required  am having problem with just passing the arguments from html form elements to this function . Am I right in figuring out or is there any thing other than this which needs consideration

Comment: Your original question was how to add methods to a class. Then your comment above asks how to add attributes to a method (doesn't make sense) and having problems passing arguments. I think you need to read up on the definitions of class, method, argument & parameter. If (as I expect) you are asking "How can I add 2 more parameters to this function/method?" then please reword the question.

Comment: Dear sir I am new to programming and don't know much about parameter passing in PHP. If you would explain how a parameter can be passed to a function it would be a lot more helpful. I mean what you expected is very right...

Comment: I've added an answer to what I now think is your question. It would be helpful if you could update this question to reflect your actual request please.

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are to edit the class itself, or to code a new class that inherits from the class and implements your two extra methods.

If you go for the inheritance approach, you would then need to update any code that instantiates that class and make it instantiate your class instead as required.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Answer (score 0):

Very generally the method/function is defined along the lines of

```
function my_function_name($param1, $param2, $param3, etc, etc...) {
  // do something with $param1
  // do something with $param2
  // do something with $param3
}
```

The parameters of the method are defined as a comma separated list. When calling the function you pass arguments (i.e. actual values) to the function. To allow the passing of more arguments you simply add more parameters to the comma separated list and then you can do whatever work you need to do in your function.

Eg your function signature is currently:

```
function update_user_by_admin($new_level, $user_id, $def_pass, $new_email, $active, $confirmation = "no", $staff_salary, $set_duty_timings) {
// do some stuff...
}
```

to add more parameters you would simply extend the function line. eg:

```
function update_user_by_admin($new_level, $user_id, $def_pass, $new_email, $active, $confirmation = "no", $staff_salary, $set_duty_timings, $another_param, $one_more) {
// do some stuff...
}
```

If you are asking how to pass arguments (the data that is received into parameters) to a function/method then you simply specify the function name followed by a comma separated list of values (and of course the semicolon required at the end of a statement in PHP). Eg.

```
my_function_name("a",2,TRUE);
```

would result in:

- param1 = "a"
- param2 = 2
- param3 = TRUE

Looking at your code in more detail I can see that the method parameters are being used to update the properties of the class. So you want to end up with something like:

```
function update_user_by_admin($new_level, $user_id, $def_pass, $new_email, $active, $confirmation = "no", $staff_salary, $set_duty_timings, $another_param, $one_more) {
    $this->user_found = true;
    $this->user_access_level = $new_level;
    $this->set_staff_salary=$staff_salary;
    // lots of other stuff
    $this->another_prop = $another_param;
    $this->one_more_prop = $one_more;
}
```

You would also need to add the extra properties to the class but as you haven't posted the class details here I cannot help you with that presently.

Apologies if this is not what you are asking.

Comment: I have tried setting the staff salary and get its value from the html code like this but does not work                                                                                                                                       `code`  <?php echo $admin_update->staff_salary($admin_update->staff_salary);?>
  <input type="text" name="salary" size="15" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['salary'])) ? $_POST['salary'] : ""; ?>"><br>

Comment: I have not mentioned the class code here because it inherits from another class and is a derived one if you can sort out what I am missing then plz tell me I will post the entire class code

Comment: I would have expected you to be using an object reference rather than the $_POST array. On first glance it also looks like you have your brackets in the wrong place. Shouldn't it be 
`<?php echo (isset($_POST['salary']) ? $_POST['salary'] : ""); ?>`
In any event I think you need to isolate your problem to see whether it is occurring when storing the values or retrieving them. See http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php or google `debugging php` for further help in doing this.

Comment: I am having problem in storing them thank you for your contribution I am amazed if a teacher could help it that way. You are awesome sir . Hats of...and I am not lying .....

Comment: You should have all of the information you need now to solve your problem. Without further details I think there is nothing more we can do to help you.